# Move Forward or Backward doen't work when reload Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, bxslider

I'm using bxSlider and I'va the following cenario

When a specific Year is selected, I need reload the month with just the months that had values in the clicked Year.

My problem is, when the reload occurs, I loose the arrow controls, i.e., I can't move forwards or backward.

```
self.UpdateMensalTab = function (year, tab) {
    var url2 = _URL_UPDATE_TAB_MENSAL_;
    $(".slider2").html("");
    $.ajax({
        url: url2,
        type: 'POST',
        async: true,
        dataType: 'html',
        data: { "Year": year },
        success: function(result) {
            $(".slider2").html(result);
        }
    });

    $('.slider2').bxSlider({
        pager: false,
        infiniteLoop: false,
        slideWidth: 100,
        minSlides: 6,
        maxSlides: 6,
        slideMargin: 1,
        autoControls: true,
        adaptiveHeight: true,
        startSlide: 1
    });
}
```

**Image**

Both buttons to move forward or backward, doesn't work anymore even there have data to show. Can anyone help me ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bxSlider has a function called `reloadSlider`. 
you can use like

```
var slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    mode: 'horizontal'
});

$('#reload-slider').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    slider.reloadSlider({
        mode: 'fade',
        auto: true,
        pause: 1000,
        speed: 500
    });
});
```

for more details refer [this](http://bxslider.com/examples/reload-slider)

Also you should refresh the slider AFTER the new content is added.

```
self.UpdateMensalTab = function (year, tab) {
    var url2 = _URL_UPDATE_TAB_MENSAL_;

    $(".slider2").html("");

    window.slider = $('.slider2').bxSlider({
        pager: false,
        infiniteLoop: false,
        slideWidth: 100,
        minSlides: 6,
        maxSlides: 6,
        slideMargin: 1,
        autoControls: true,
        adaptiveHeight: true,
        startSlide: 1
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: url2,
        type: 'POST',
        async: true,
        dataType: 'html',
        data: { "Year": year },
        success: function(result) {
            $(".slider2").html(result);
            window.slider.reloadSlider({
                pager: false,
                infiniteLoop: false,
                slideWidth: 100,
                minSlides: 6,
                maxSlides: 6,
                slideMargin: 1,
                autoControls: true,
                adaptiveHeight: true,
                startSlide: 1
            });
        }
    });
}
```